# how to configure karaf/etc files during runtime from bundles programatically?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-karaf

Is there a possible way to change karaf/etc org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg file contents during runtime through a bundle? My requirement is to reload

```
log4j.appender.TestAppender.File=/home/log.txt
```

in runtime without restarting karaf. I did some coding to change File name in runtime but the classloader not taking the changed one instead it takes the 'log.txt' as a default logging file.. But the changed files are getting created with empty content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your TestAppender bound to the pax-logging bundle? If this class isn't accessible you'll need to add this to the pax-logging bundle by using a fragment. 
For details take a look at this blog: 
[Adding custom log appender to pax-logging](http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2011/08/adding-custom-log-appender-to-pax-logging/)

Comment: Im having my appenders as a part of org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.cfg file like `log4j.logger.TestAppender=TRACE,Test` it works fine in static environment.. But during runtime when I change my file name, the logging doesn't goes to the changed one and it goes to the hard coded one in cfg file. Although different files are getting created..